# non-staticHow To Use "getSystemService" in Custom Spinner

Tags: android, custom-controls

I Need To Use "getSystemService" In Custom Spinner, So Custom Spinner Extends

> getSystemService  Will Use To Copy Text To Clip Board is non-static

And I Am unable To Use It In Custom Spinner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO, a custom `Spinner` subclass has no business working with the clipboard. That is the responsibility of the fragment or activity that hosts the `Spinner`.

That being said, call `getContext().getSystemService()` from a method on a `View`.